# ActiveMQ Camel: Every other message sends with multicast

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to route an XML packet from one ActiveMQ queue to another ActiveMQ queue on another box. I am using camel to achieve this. I intend to send it to other boxes later so I am using the multicast to duplicate the message.

I am sending and receiving the messages using the [C-Stomp library](https://github.com/codehaus/stomp/tree/master/c) on both ends.

ActiveMQ-5.9.0 and Camel-2.12.3

```
camel.xml

<camelContext>
  <route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:out" />
    <multicast>
      <to uri="otheractivemq:queue:in" />
    </multicast>
  </route>
</camelContext>

<!-- ActiveMQs -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
      <property name="userName" value="${activemq.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="otheractivemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://[differentip]:61616"/>
      <property name="userName" value="${activemq.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

On my ActiveMQ broker, I can see that messages are being added into the queue on the local side the promptly dequeued; but, when I check the other ActiveMQ, only every other message gets enqueued.

I attempted to add a "clone" of the destination queue on the other box and added it to the multicast; so, my route liked like the following:

```
<route>
  <from uri="activemq:queue:out" />
  <multicast>
    <to uri="otheractivemq:queue:in" />
    <to uri="otheractivemq:queue:in_clone" />
  </multicast>
</route>
```

But, then the "clone" only received every other message, while the other queue received them all.